# HTML 'id' attribute for items in dropdown made from html helper

Tags: asp.net, html-helper

Can we set an id attribute as I would for something like a table column via:

for an html dropdown list element that is created with a helper such as:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection.Count; i++)
{%>
    <%= i > 0 ? "," : "" %>
    <%= DropDownData.HolidayDays().ToList().Find(item => item.Value == Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection[i].HolidayCityID.Value.ToString()).Text  %>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a helper, necessarily:

```
<select id="holidayCities" name="holidayCities">
<% foreach (HolidayCity city in Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection) { %>
    <option 
        value="<%=city.HolidayCityID.Value %>"
        id="holidayCity_<%=city.HolidayCityID.Value %>"
    ><%=city.Name %></option>
<% } %>
</select>
```

---

If you wanted to use the HtmlHelper you can write:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("holidayCities", Model.HolidayCitiesSelectList) %>
```

`Model.HolidayCitiesSelectList` should be of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

---

This type of customization isn't avaiable for the built in helpers so you might end up creating your own Html.DropDownList helper method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: That gives an id for the select list as a whole. We have that already. We would want one for each element in the list. It's easy if you do it without helpers, but with a helper we are not given HTML markup access to each select list item tag.

Comment: why would you need to reference the `<option>` by Id? Can't you reference it by it's `value`?

Comment: I've never had a need, but `id` is a valid attribute for `<option>` - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp. See updates